# Is it possible to use tabpy without a server?

Tags: tableau-api, tabpy

I know that to use tabpy, I have to "start up" Tabpy Server, as it says here - https://github.com/tableau/TabPy/blob/master/docs/server-startup.md - but  I don't have a server. Is it still possible to use tabpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `python tabpy.py --config=path\to\my\config` it starts up the "server".  You don't need an actual server to run this program.  It is called a server because it accepts requests and forwards them to Python/R/Matlab services.